# ¿Cómo agrupo datos en categorias en PHP?

Tags: php, sql-server, vscode

pasa que hice una consulta en SQL SERVER, pero a la hora de pasarla a PHP no se ve como espero, y no tengo idea de como formular la consulta en el visual code, y lo que quiero es que mis datos se agrupen en categorias, por ejemplo si el alumno tiene de "14 a 17 años" Va en 'Bachiiler'.

Así se ve mi consulta en el visual code:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y quiero que se me agrupen como en mi base de datos, así se muestra en SQL SERVER:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Así la formule en visual code:

```
<?php

include "Conexion.php";

$sql = "SELECT (nombre + ' ' + paterno + ' ' + materno) as Nombre_Completo, edad as Edad
FROM alumnos
WHERE edad !=0

SELECT *, 'Aspirante' as Nivel_Academico FROM vEdades WHERE Edad < 11
UNION
SELECT *, 'Secundaria' as Nivel_Academico FROM vEdades WHERE Edad BETWEEN 11 and 14
UNION
SELECT *, 'Bachiller' as Nivel_Academico FROM vEdades WHERE Edad BETWEEN 15 and 17
UNION
SELECT *, 'Universidad' as Nivel_Academico FROM vEdades WHERE Edad BETWEEN 18 and 24
UNION
SELECT *, 'Egresado' as Nivel_Academico FROM vEdades WHERE Edad > 24

ORDER BY Nivel_Academico asc";

$stmt = sqlsrv_query( $conn, $sql );
if( $stmt === false) {
    die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true) );
}

while( $row = sqlsrv_fetch_array( $stmt, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC) ) {
    echo $row['Nombre_Completo'].", ".$row['Edad']."<br />";
}

sqlsrv_free_stmt( $stmt);

?>
```

O al menos saber como se le llama a este tipo de ejercicio.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Realizar tantos UNION es lo que se conoce como matar moscas a cañonazos.

Lo que pretendes hacer es realizar una sencilla consulta SELECT sobre la tabla alumnos donde además de los campos nombre_completo y edad, el motor de la base de datos te devuelva un campo calculado nuevo que se determine a partir del campo almacenado edad. Esto último se consigue con la instrucción [CASE](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/sql/t-sql/language-elements/case-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15).

He creado un [ejemplo demostrativo en SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/68c82d/1/0) con las siguiente estructura y datos

```
CREATE TABLE Alumnos (
    idAlumno varchar (4) PRIMARY KEY,
    nombre varchar (30) NOT NULL,
    paterno varchar (30) NOT NULL,
    materno varchar (30) NOT NULL,
    edad int NOT NULL
);
    

INSERT INTO Alumnos (idAlumno, nombre, paterno, materno, edad) VALUES
('0001', 'Pablo', 'Rubio', 'Sánchez', 40),
('0002', 'Juan', 'Trujillo', 'Crespo', 20),
('0003', 'Ignacio', 'Luque', 'Luengo', 18),
('0004', 'Javier', 'López', 'Hernández', 31),
('0005', 'Antonio', 'Calderón', 'Calderón', 11),
('0006', 'Juande', 'Jiménez', 'Mérida', 16),
('0007', 'Carlos', 'Periago', 'Romera', 10);
```

Creo que la siguiente consulta obtiene los datos que quieres

```
SELECT (nombre + ' ' + paterno + ' ' + materno) as Nombre_Completo, 
        edad as Edad,
        CASE
           WHEN (edad < 11) THEN 'Aspirante'
           WHEN (edad >= 11 AND edad <= 14) THEN 'Secundaria'
           WHEN (edad >= 15 AND edad <= 17) THEN 'Bachiller'
           WHEN (edad >= 18 AND edad <= 24) THEN 'Egresado'
           WHEN (edad > 24) THEN 'Universidad'
        END AS Nivel_Academico
FROM Alumnos
WHERE edad !=0
ORDER BY Nivel_Academico ASC;
```

Resultado

| Nombre_Completo | Edad | Nivel_Academico |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Carlos Periago Romera | 10 | Aspirante |
| Juande Jiménez Mérida | 16 | Bachiller |
| Juan Trujillo Crespo | 20 | Egresado |
| Ignacio Luque Luengo | 18 | Egresado |
| Antonio Calderón Calderón | 11 | Secundaria |
| Pablo Rubio Sánchez | 40 | Universidad |
| Javier López Hernández | 31 | Universidad |

La clausula CASE funciona igual que un if-else, dependiendo de qué condición cumpla el valor del campo almacenado en la tabla, en nuestro caso edad, te devolverá un valor u otro para el Nivel_Académico.

Este tipo de clausula también permite un valor por defecto, es decir puedes indicarle qué tiene que devolver en caso de que no se cumplan ninguna de las condiciones especificadas. Esto se consigue añadiendo una línea **ELSE** al final.

```
SELECT (nombre + ' ' + paterno + ' ' + materno) as Nombre_Completo, 
            edad as Edad,
            CASE
               WHEN (edad < 11) THEN 'Aspirante'
               WHEN (edad >= 11 AND edad <= 14) THEN 'Secundaria'
               WHEN (edad >= 15 AND edad <= 17) THEN 'Bachiller'
               WHEN (edad >= 18 AND edad <= 24) THEN 'Egresado'
               ELSE 'Universidad'
            END AS Nivel_Academico
    FROM Alumnos
    WHERE edad !=0
    ORDER BY Nivel_Academico ASC;
```

Para próximas preguntas que puedas hacer de SQL, sería útil que añadieras los CREATE TABLE y los INSERT con un juego de datos mínimos, como los que yo he puesto, para que quien intente ayudarte tenga más fácil reproducir tu error o la situación que plantees.

En PHP solo tendrías que sustituir el valor de `$sql` por la consulta que he puesto arriba. Y luego puedes acceder al nuevo campo con `$row['Nivel_Academico']`

Comment: Increíble, no tenía ni idea de como estructurarla...
Tengo una duda respecto a la consulta que ha realizado (php), es posible usar esa consulta para visualizar los datos en gráficas (charts) en vez de tablas (?)

Comment: @Griggle Supongo que sí, que es posible, pero no se trata de una cosa trivial. Que yo sepa las gráficas no vienen instaladas en el paquete básico de PHP. Tendrías que instalar una librería y aprender a usarla. Algo como esto https://phpchart.com/ o esto https://jpgraph.net/

Comment: Ya veo! pero estoy usando visual code y solo se necesitan los js para los charts

Comment: @Griggle ¿Te refieres a esto? https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=RandomFractalsInc.vscode-chartjs Ten en cuenta que los ejemplos que salen ahí son estáticos. Para que sean dinámicos, que salgan distintos gráficos dependiendo de los datos que hay en la base de datos recuperados por PHP, tendrías que hacer algo como esto https://programacion.net/articulo/como_crear_un_grafico_de_datos_dinamico_mediante_chart_js_y_php_2009

Comment: @RubioRic +1 increíble tu respuesta, gracias, hoy he aprendido algo nuevo, ni te imaginas cuanto código php me has ahorrado con tu ejemplo, muy buena la clausula CASE

Comment: @AugustoDanielRuyz De nada, hombre! :-)

Answer (score 0):

no veo necesidad de la primera sentencia, eso lo puedes hacer con php

**defines el Nivel_Academico, en la primera sentencia evitas la edad 0, y en la ultima ordenas por la edad**

```sql
SELECT *, 'Aspirante' as Nivel_Academico FROM alumnos WHERE edad < 11 AND edad!=0
UNION
SELECT *, 'Secundaria' as Nivel_Academico FROM alumnos WHERE edad BETWEEN 11 and 14
UNION
SELECT *, 'Bachiller' as Nivel_Academico FROM alumnos WHERE edad BETWEEN 15 and 17
UNION
SELECT *, 'Universidad' as Nivel_Academico FROM alumnos WHERE edad BETWEEN 18 and 24
UNION
SELECT *, 'Egresado' as Nivel_Academico FROM alumnos WHERE edad > 24
ORDER BY edad asc
```

**luego simplemente con PHP juntas el nombre completo**

```php
while( $row = sqlsrv_fetch_array( $stmt, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC) ) {
    echo $row['nombre']." ".$row['paterno']." ".$row['materno'];
    echo ", ".$row['edad'];
    echo ", ".$row['Nivel_Academico'];
    echo "<br />";
}
```